# How to compare two different models?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I trained a new regression model and want to compare its performance against the benchmark model. If the models have similar RMSE and MAE but different R-squared values (the benchmark model R2 is much lower). How to understand which one is performing better.

Answer (score -1):

R Squared value is the measure of goodness of fit of Regression models and ranges between 0-100%

0% means that the model does not explain the variation of the response variable around its mean and 100% means it explains all the variation
Usually larger the value of R squared, the better the data fits your model.
But there's an important point to remember:

A lower R-squared value is always not bad because there are several areas of study that exist in which you'll find unexplainable variation and the value is bound to be lower but still it can be used to draw some conclusions.

Conclusion- A model with a larger R-squared value does not necessarily mean a good model and the one with the smaller value is always not a bad model. It depends on your field of study and you can use the R-squared value along with the residual plot of your data to understand the goodness of fit by visualizing it.
To learn more you can read [this](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-r-squared-regression/).

I hope you find this helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Comparing model performance is relative to the task you have and the goal of your project. I would recommend allocating time to decide what constitutes as better performance.

Here are some things to consider:

**Overall accuracy**

Compare MAE/MSE/R-squared across a test set. It sounds like you have already done this - however I am surprised that you said both models have similar RMSE but different R-squared since they are related quantities. I would advise checking there are no bugs in your code OR consider reavaluating what you mean by *similar RMSE*.
Consider also adding MAPE (Mean Average Percentage Error) to your repertoire since percentages are more intuitively interpreted and compared that things like MAE.

**Computational time**

Computation resources are often valuable. If you are running models through AWS or GCC then you can likely translate model training, hyperparameter tuning, and model evaluations to $$$. If two models have comparable performance but one is costing you less to run then that is something you should keep in mind. The significance of this depends on how often you plan on training, optimising hyperparameters, feature selection, or function use, and how much you are willing to pay for an increase in accuracy.

Another importance is how fast it takes to get results. If this is being used in an API where human waiting time for the computer to churn out a result is significant, then this is something to consider. Another scenario where time is important is if it's time consuming to train and fine-tune a model when you (or worse, someone else) are wanting results quickly.

**Edge / border cases**

Are there obscure / unusual cases / atypical that are important which one model can predict over another? These do not have to be obscure but simply occur less frequently in the data sets, and since they are rare they may not contribute significantly to overall accuracy. However, the benefit of being able to cover more cases may significantly improve your use cases.

**Variance of accuracy**

Similar to edge/border cases. Instead of MAE or overall accuracy, it may be the case that your accuracy for each model output is either *good enough* or *not good enough* and that a more meaningful metric is to evaluate the percentage of times your model output is *good enough*. It may be that one model has a higher overall accuracy, but this is distributed across some scenarios where accuracy is exceptionally high and others where it is low. It may be favourable to have a *good enough* prediction 100% of the times than an *exceptional accuracy* most of the time and *not good enough* some of the time.

**Behaviour**

Sometimes the behaviour of one model is favourable to another, even though there may be little difference seen in error metrics. The term *behaviour* here  is subjective, but it can be:

1. Are there unwanted fluctuations in output seen in one model over another?
2. Do similar inputs give significantly different outputs?
3. Do you occasionally make wildly inaccurate predictions?
4. How similar is model behaviour to a human performing the same task?
5. Does the regression increase/decrease in scenarios you expect it to?

**Performance on test cases**

Oftentimes models are trained in different circumstances to how they are used in production. Having a collection of production use-cases with an idea of what performance you are wanting can help to evaluate your model, especially in circumstances where model performance is subjective.

Which brings me on to what is probably the most important thing to consider:

**What is your model actually being used for?**

What problem are you actually trying to solve? If your goal is to create a model with less overall MSE then use the one with less MSE. If not then try to write down exactly what the goal is and how you are going to measure it. Consider writing OKRs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OKR

I regularly get into this scenario myself but I do consider it a core issue to the purpose of my work if ever I cannot immediately answer the question: has this made a significant and demonstratable improvement?

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is no bug in the code. The benchmark model is perform poorly which was expected and I wanted to build a new model to see if it can perform slightly better. The RMSE are 0.51 and .56 and R2 are 0.19 and 0.02! I calcualted the MAPE those are also very close 22 and 24